# Meaning of Active Record Encryption fields (p, h, iv, at, k, p, h, iv, at, e)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, activerecord

Let's say I encrypted a field with the secret key `correct`, I get:

```
=> {"p"=>"dIc=",
 "h"=>
  {"iv"=>"PrL87KzAKv7ZataS",
   "at"=>"w9oq5XX+l2qYCWG5Ce4QIQ==",
   "k"=>
    {"p"=>"N8zOKHTloKk92d20y1pPthX2DSdooPdhgQvrnDtfBME=",
     "h"=>
      {"iv"=>"NqNkA4i76VNPjIPf",
       "at"=>"BGFek3jhD4dEf5hmIpxoBA==",
       "e"=>"QVNDSUktOEJJVA=="}}}}
```

What does those fields mean? How can I know which key was used to encrypt the field?

Here it is decoded from base64:

```
=> {"p"=>"t\x87",
 "h"=>
  {"iv"=>">\xB2\xFC\xEC\xAC\xC0*\xFE\xD9j\xD6\x92",
   "at"=>"\xC3\xDA*\xE5u\xFE\x97j\x98\ta\xB9\t\xEE\x10!",
   "k"=>
    {"p"=>"7\xCC\xCE(t\xE5\xA0\xA9=\xD9\xDD\xB4\xCBZO\xB6\x15\xF6\r'h\xA0\xF7a\x81\v\xEB\x9C;_\x04\xC1",
     "h"=>{"iv"=>"6\xA3d\x03\x88\xBB\xE9SO\x8C\x83\xDF", "at"=>"\x04a^\x93x\xE1\x0F\x87D\x7F\x98f\"\x9Ch\x04", "e"=>"ASCII-8BIT"}}}}
```

So I guess `e` is the encoding

Answer (score 1):

So `p` is the payload, and `h` are the headers. Here's the map of the default headers:

```rb
irb(main):005> ActiveRecord::Encryption::Properties::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES
=> {:encrypted_data_key=>"k", :encrypted_data_key_id=>"i", :compressed=>"c", :iv=>"iv", :auth_tag=>"at", :encoding=>"e"}
```